# Could not start Burp: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no splashscreen in java.library.path

Tags: java, runtime-error, burp

When trying to run BurpSuite on linux manjaro the following error occurs: "Could not start Burp: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no splashscreen in java.library.path"

java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error. Fixed it 2 minutes ago with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-14-jre
```

Then just re-run burpsuite, and it will launch.

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide some context about what the command in your answer intends to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Recently encountered the same error message on Ubuntu.

I Fixed It **uninstalling JDK and running burp installer again.**(*Burp installer includes OpenJDK 12 which is used by BurpSuite.*)

Finally I ran BurpSuiteCommunity from terminal instead of burpsuite_community.jar. Hopefully that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me because i have updated Java.
Then to solve I just uninstalled the JAVA update

and fixed(changed) environment variables respectively.

Now Burp suite works as it was working before!